# How can I set unit value when I use uvc_set_ctrl() and uvc_get_ctrl() in libuvc?

Tags: c++, c

I try to control USB camera with libuvc on Ubuntu 20.04.
when the ctrl value = 0x400 and the unit value = 0x200,
I can call `uvc_set_ctrl(device_handle, 0x4, 0x2, output_buffer, buffer_length)`, and it's successful to set value to specify register.

But how can I offer value to `uvc_set_ctrl()` when the unit value = `0x303`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, there,
I download libuvc source code from https://github.com/libuvc/libuvc, and use uvc_set_ctrl() for register access. 
In ctrl.c (https://github.com/libuvc/libuvc/blob/master/src/ctrl.c), I found 
int uvc_set_ctrl(uvc_device_handle_t *devh, uint8_t unit, uint8_t ctrl, void *data, int len) {
  return libusb_control_transfer(
    devh->usb_devh,
    REQ_TYPE_SET, UVC_SET_CUR,
    ctrl << 8,
    unit << 8 | devh->info->ctrl_if.bInterfaceNumber,  
    data,
    len,
    0 );
}

Could somebody tell me if I misunderstand something ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu, to solve this issue, you can follow the following steps:

1. In `libuvc.h`, declare these two functions:

```
int uvc_get_ctrl1(uvc_device_handle_t *devh, uint16_t unit, uint16_t ctrl, void *data, int len, enum uvc_req_code req_code);

int uvc_set_ctrl1(uvc_device_handle_t *devh, uint16_t unit, uint16_t ctrl, void *data, int len);
```

2. In `ctrl.c`, create these two functions:

```
int uvc_get_ctrl1(uvc_device_handle_t *devh, uint16_t unit, uint16_t ctrl, void *data, int len, enum uvc_req_code req_code) {
      return libusb_control_transfer(
        devh->usb_devh,
        REQ_TYPE_GET, req_code,
        ctrl,
        unit,       
        data,
        len,
        0 /* timeout */);
}
    
int uvc_set_ctrl1(uvc_device_handle_t *devh, uint16_t unit, uint16_t ctrl, void *data, int len) {
      return libusb_control_transfer(
        devh->usb_devh,
        REQ_TYPE_SET, UVC_SET_CUR,
        ctrl,
        unit,       
        data,
        len,
        0 /* timeout */);
}
```

3. Rebuild your `libuvc`. You can run the shell commands below:

If you already had a `build` folder, please delete this folder first.

```
cd libuvc
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make && sudo make install
```

In your program, you can call `uvc_get_ctrl1()` and `uvc_set_ctrl1()` if your `ctrl` value and `unit` value are `0x303` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

These are library-specific functions -- different implementations of UVC (for example on Windows) won't have these, so I think your question would be better suited to the `libuvc` forum.

For what it's worth, I tried looking at the libuvc documentation to read about `uvc_set_ctrl`, but the URL for the documentation on the README page isn't valid anymore: https://int80k.com/libuvc/doc/

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Mr. Raleigh L., Thanks for your answer. At the moment, I consider to use libusb in Ubuntu.